# How to make the second for timer move using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom

This function will show the date and time. As for the time it will show like this format "00:00:00", however the 'second' does not move only static. Below is the code:

```
function isDst(d) {
    var dst = 60; // DST on by default.

    // Up until March 9 switch off DST.
    if ((d.getMonth() < 3) && (d.getDate() < 10)) { dst = 0; }

    // After November 2 switch off DST.
    if ((d.getMonth() > 9) && (d.getDate() > 2)) { dst = 0; }

    return dst;
}

function init() {
    var panel = document.getElementById("panel");
    var now = new Date()  
    var offset = now.getTimezoneOffset();
    var dst = isDst(now);
    switch (offset) {
        case (300 - dst): offset = "East Coast"; break;
        case (360 - dst): offset = "Central"; break;
        case (420 - dst): offset = "Mountain"; break;
        case (480 - dst): offset = "Pacific"; break;
        default: offset = "all";
    }
    panel.innerHTML = "Date and Time: " + now.toString() + "<hr>Welcome to " + offset + " visitors";
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want the text on the site to update every second.

Your script doesn't work because you are setting the innerHTML of #panel to a string that was created using the current time. There is nothing in the HTML to tell the browser to update the string. You have to add your own code in JavaScript.

The easiest way to do this is to use the window.setInterval(); function. Make a function that updates your text to have the current time then call window.setInterval(myFunc, 1000). Note the lack of parentheses on myFunc. This means that you will be passing the **function** myFunc not the **return value** of myFunc. The second argument is the number of milliseconds to wait before calling the function again. window.setInterval calls myFunc every 1000 millisecondsl if you want to call myFunc once use setTimeout.

Taking all that together, to make your script work you need to append this line:

```
window.setInterval(init, 1000);
```

Enjoy!